# DocuSign - push pdf to CRM

Tags: docusignapi

I have made an embedded DocuSign envelope that gets populated with user generated content. It works, I'm just wondering if I can somehow capture the generated pdf and do something with it, like push it to a CRM as an attachment upon successful signing.

I wasn't having much luck while searching for it, so is this possible with the DocuSign API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the PDF before it was signed or after it has been completed (signed by all the recipients)?

I'll assume the latter. Best way to process an envelope after it is signed, including storing the signed document(s) and any attachments uploaded by the recipients, is to use the Connect feature.

With Connect, your app registers itself with DocuSign as a webhook. Your app then receives a push notification that can include the documents, after each event that you're subscribed to.

You can also use the API to directly download the documents associated with an envelope. See the API's [EnvelopeDocuments Resource](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/).

More information:

- [Webhooks: Don’t Poll Us, We’ll Call You!](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhooks-dont-poll-us-well-call/)
- [Securing Your Connect Webhook Listener](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/)
- [Using Connect’s New Send Individual Messages Feature](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-connect-send-individual-messages/)
- [DocuSign Connect Now Includes Basic Authentication Support](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-connect-basic-authentication-support/)